# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers. Due to the submission count, we have selected all the submitted questions, plus our base 2 and 2 extra questions, for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/8cbd873d-0f47-4f1b-b1ef-8c09879674a3/view-source). Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

- [Adrian Larson](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/2436#2436)
- [Ashwani Soni](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/2437#2437)
- [crmprogdev - Cal Smith](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2439/2212)
- [Mohith Shrivastava](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/2436#2438)

---

> 1. **What voting practices would you encourage users to adopt?** This kind of dates back to [Why aren't people voting?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/102) and how to encourage a positive community through voting. How can we use our votes to encourage useful questions and answers?
> 2. **Are you currently employed by Salesforce (Such as the Developer Evangelists)?** We've previously had [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) as a moderator who was at the time on the Salesforce Developer Evangelists team. I felt this was a large benefit to the SFSE community as a bridge into Salesforce. It's certainly not a requirement to being a moderator.
> 3. **How do you plan to manage the quality of new user posts?** We get a flood of new users each month, and in general that is a good thing! We want our community to grow. But the question quality is often quite poor, and there is a learning curve to adding valuable content on the Stack Exchange, with different subtleties for questions and answers.
> 4. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 5. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 6. **As a moderator, how can we help to increase the acceptance rate?** being with the site for few years now, one thing I see different compared to salesforce developer forums or success community is a large percentage of our questions stays open without any accepted answers. how can moderators pitch in to help increase this and what considerations should be taken care in doing this?
> 7. **How would you encourage User participation off SFSE?** I haven't been fortunate to go to Dreamforce (yet!), but do attend the Salesforce World Tour in London and I've often seen posts around Dreamforce and other World Tour meetups which is great. How might a moderator go about encouraging people to engage outside of Stack Exchange?
> 8. **How would you be managing the flag/action to be taken on the SFSE in parallel to your daily work?** As the site in continuously growing and everyday new users joining it. This would generate a lot of expected and unexpected posts to the site which require action by moderators. I would like the know response time to be taken by moderator to resolve those actions. Do you commit to allocate a time slot to investigate and resolve flags?
> 9. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: Voting on answers on this thread doesn't mean anything in terms of the election, right?

Comment: Correct, they do not

Comment: Doesn't seem like we need to feature this one any more. :)

Answer (score 16):

## **[crmprogdev - Cal Smith](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2212/crmprogdev)**

> 1. **What voting practices would you encourage users to adopt?** This kind of dates back to [Why aren't people voting?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/102) and how to encourage a positive community through voting. How can we use our votes to encourage useful questions and answers?

**a.** I would encourage users to upvote both **Questions** and **Answers**. We see far too many **Answers** being upvoted than we do **Questions**.

**b.** If a question is clearly written and demonstrates that a reasonable attempt has been made to solve or understand it, I think it merits an upvote.

**c.** I would discourage users from downvoting questions from new users. To me, that's a poor way to welcome someone to our forum.

**d.** Even for users with reputation, if you're going to downvote, take a moment to explain what's "wrong" with their post and how they can improve it.

---

> 2. **Are you currently employed by Salesforce (Such as the Developer Evangelists)?** We've previously had [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) as a moderator who was at the time on the Salesforce Developer Evangelists team. I felt this was a large benefit to the SFSE community as a bridge into Salesforce. It's certainly not a requirement to being a moderator.

**a.** No, I'm not employed by Salesforce. As an MVP, I do have additional access to many resources within Salesforce that others may not have which often includes the ability to reach out to product managers.

**b.** Over the years, I've cultivated many resources and have learned how to "work the sytstem" where I can. I've often used #AskSalesforce on Twitter to get Salesforce Support to look at questions here on SF.SE. Doing that has frequently assisted users in getting cases filed to receive the attention they needed from Salesforce in resolving their issues.

> 3. **How do you plan to manage the quality of new user posts?** We get a flood of new users each month, and in general that is a good thing! We want our community to grow. But the question quality is often quite poor, and there is a learning curve to adding valuable content on the Stack Exchange, with different subtleties for questions and answers.

**a.** I've frequently spoken out in Meta on how important I felt it was that we be welcoming toward new users instead of downvoting their questions without making helpful suggestions on how to improve their questions. You'll see this in answers I've posted on Meta like [A:Repetive Questions](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2141/repetitive-questions/2142?s=2%7C0.0000#2142) or [A:How to Encourage Better Questions?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/883/how-to-encourage-better-questions/884?s=10%7C0.0000#884).

**b.** As I said above, I would discourage users from downvoting questions from new users. To me, that's a poor way to welcome someone to our forum. Instead, I recommend using one of the many snippets I posted in [this answer on Meta](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/expecting-end-to-end-apex-code-as-an-answer/2011?s=6%7C0.0000#2011) to politely welcome new users to SF.SE while also helping them learn how our forum works; something which I increasingly see users doing. Pointing them to a helpful resource like a relevant Trailhead Module to get what they need is always good too.

> 4. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

**a.** We're all here to learn. Some of us have "different" things we need to learn in life. Rarely does one "win" a debate on the internet. That may be a lesson those users may need to learn.

**b.** Sometimes being given a "[time out](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)" away from the forum can provide them with a chance to gain the perspective they need to learn that lesson; allowing them to come back with a new perspective. These things can be handled quietly without "shaming" anyone publicly.

> 5. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

**a.** I have great respect for the other mods here on SF.SE. They have far more experience at this than I do. I can always ask what their reasoning was behind the decision and calmly explain mine. They may have reasons that I didn't see or understand. We can agree to disagree and I can learn from their experience.

**b.** Ultimately, this is a team effort where everyone will be doing their "best". That's all we can expect. It's important that we support one another's decisions.

> 6. **As a moderator, how can we help to increase the acceptance rate?** being with the site for few years now, one thing I see different compared to salesforce developer forums or success community is a large percentage of our questions stays open without any accepted answers. how can moderators pitch in to help increase this and what considerations should be taken care in doing this?

**a.** When I see a user "thank" someone in comments for an answer that's been given, I'd see that as an opportunity to explain how the forum works and drop one of my snippets on them along the lines of:

"@(username) Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can also upvote posts and answers."

> 7. **How would you encourage User participation off SFSE?** I haven't been fortunate to go to Dreamforce (yet!), but do attend the Salesforce World Tour in London and I've often seen posts around Dreamforce and other World Tour meetups which is great. How might a moderator go about encouraging people to engage outside of Stack Exchange?

**a.** I think it's great when users get together outside of the forum, something I've done myself. There are many avenues for doing that, including Dreamforce, UserGroups, Developer User Groups, World Tours, the "Dreamin" events, etc.

**b.** Let me first say that these events are jam packed full of activities to begin with so scheduling time for SF.SE users to gather together can be a challenge.

**c.** This is really going to be up to someone taking the lead who's attending these events to organize a time and place to meet and I'll fully support posts in Meta for anyone who wants to organize a get together at one of these events.

**d.** Beyond that, I don't see it as falling within this forum's purpose or a moderator's duties to organize events.

> 8. **How would you be managing the flag/action to be taken on the SFSE in parallel to your daily work?** As the site in continuously growing and everyday new users joining it. This would generate a lot of expected and unexpected posts to the site which require action by moderators. I would like the know response time to be taken by moderator to resolve those actions. Do you commit to allocate a time slot to investigate and resolve flags?

**a.** I'm here nearly every day for at least an hour and often more now that I've finally adjusted to the added load that comes with becoming an MVP (believe me when I say it's more than a bit overwhelming at first).

**b.** I think people know and recognize that I've been here consistently for the last several years and I don't see that changing.

> 9. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

**a.** Most of us don't get to see what moderators actually do. Their most important responsibilities are to handle flagged posts and to review what happens in the queues that may or may not be appropriate. They also represent us on Meta.

**b.** They also migrate posts that didn't belong elsewhere from meta or from the main forum to meta, etc.

**c.** Now that I've had the reputation to see it, I know they have the tools to identify and do what's needed to shut down extended conversations that need to be moved to chat.

**d.** They can also use their black diamond to immediately delete spam or close inappropriate posts.

**e.** In many ways, they're the primary "curators" of the forum's archive of posts.

**f.** One of the most effective things they can do is set the "tone" of the forum with the comments they make below posts.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

**a.** As I'm now over 25k, reachine the above repution levels is rather a moot issue for me. I'm not here to gain reputation.

**b.** I'm here to "pass it forward" and help others "learn to fish". Being a moderator would be a different way of doing that for me.

**c.** It would be continuing to contribute to the success of this forum while working in conjunction with @MattLacey and @SamuelDeRycke, both of whom I consider friends. I've met both of them in person and we've talked outside the forum. I think I'd work well with both of them.

Answer (score 14):

## [Adrian Larson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995)

> 1. **What voting practices would you encourage users to adopt?** This kind of dates back to [Why aren't people voting?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/102) and how to encourage a positive community through voting. How can we use our votes to encourage useful questions and answers?

I encourage users to vote according to the guidelines! If a question shows research and it is useful and clear, it deserves an upvote! It doesn't cost anything to vote a question or answer up (other than the minor chance you will run out of votes in a given day). Vote more! I especially keep an eye out for our newer up-and-coming contributors and make sure to vote for their posts (as long as they are deserving). A regular answer provider joining our ranks is great news, and I love to see it.

---

> 2. **Are you currently employed by Salesforce (Such as the Developer Evangelists)?** We've previously had [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) as a moderator who was at the time on the Salesforce Developer Evangelists team. I felt this was a large benefit to the SFSE community as a bridge into Salesforce. It's certainly not a requirement to being a moderator.

I do not work for Salesforce, nor have I at any point in the past.

---

> 3. **How do you plan to manage the quality of new user posts?** We get a flood of new users each month, and in general that is a good thing! We want our community to grow. But the question quality is often quite poor, and there is a learning curve to adding valuable content on the Stack Exchange, with different subtleties for questions and answers.

Edits and comments are the first tools out of the box. Often I will fix up tags and formatting, edit out TIA, etc, and I will continue to do so if elected. As for comments, here's a template I tend to go to:

> > Welcome to SFSE, SomeNewUser! Please take the time to visit the [help] and read [ask]. The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that the community will respond with an answer you'll find helpful. Without your code or details about your use-case, it's difficult for anyone to know how to help you.

Everything after the first sentence is subject to change depending on what the post needs. I strive to make this feedback as specific and constructive as possible.

---

> 4. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

First step is to reach out. Given the nature of the conversation needed in this case, email may be the best medium. Jeff Atwood lays that out in [his ground rules for account suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23661). If a written warning does not improve behavior, I would progress to account suspensions.

---

> 5. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

From what I have read of the moderator teams, they should support each other...when they think the actions taken were appropriate. It's not a carte blanche. If I think the question should not have been closed, I see a two options:

- Leave a comment if I think the matter can be cleared up quickly
- Post on Meta if I think we need to let the community decide

I'm not going to re-open unilaterally as a moderator. My preference would be to drop a comment asking the mod to reconsider and explaining why I think the question deserved to stay open. Sometimes character limits can be a difficult constraint to work within, however, or the topic may require extended discussion. In those cases, I would go to Meta instead.

---

> 6. **As a moderator, how can we help to increase the acceptance rate?** being with the site for few years now, one thing I see different compared to salesforce developer forums or success community is a large percentage of our questions stays open without any accepted answers. how can moderators pitch in to help increase this and what considerations should be taken care in doing this?

Most of the time, I think the problem is with new users who do not understand Stack Exchange mechanics. In this case, comment templates are the perfect tool for the job.

> > @SomeNewUser If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

I found this template on another forum and liked it enough to save it for later use. The tone is educational and not pushy.

---

> 7. **How would you encourage User participation off SFSE?** I haven't been fortunate to go to Dreamforce (yet!), but do attend the Salesforce World Tour in London and I've often seen posts around Dreamforce and other World Tour meetups which is great. How might a moderator go about encouraging people to engage outside of Stack Exchange?

Starting a local user group is on my to do list, and I would encourage the rest of our user base to do the same. I have tried to arrange some meet-and-greets in the past via Meta, but not had much success.

---

> 8. **How would you be managing the flag/action to be taken on the SFSE in parallel to your daily work?** As the site in continuously growing and everyday new users joining it. This would generate a lot of expected and unexpected posts to the site which require action by moderators. I would like the know response time to be taken by moderator to resolve those actions. Do you commit to allocate a time slot to investigate and resolve flags?

I will find the time each day to monitor moderator actions. I typically spend a half hour or more per day on the review queues that anyone with 500+ rep can monitor. We have a surplus of such users who all care deeply about the content quality in this community, so if I spend less time reviewing Close Votes and Low Quality Posts, I doubt they will pile up noticeably. Not that I intend to lessen the time I spend on those queues, but I realize that reality may force me to at some point.

---

> 9. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

As little as possible! When the site is running smoothly, the moderator team does not have to be highly visible. As human exception handlers, the team should only step in and intervene when an exception has occurred.

Hopefully we don't have to worry about suspending or deleting anyone's account, but it may happen. Moderators should also monitor flag queues, be active on Meta, and assist with tag related issues. For instance I would continue to push for deletion of the `[salesforce-crm]` tag.

Another common responsibility I see is to convert non-answers by new users into comments.

---

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

I think in some ways, it may actually be a handicap, since I will be unlikely to cast nearly as many close/reopen votes if they become binding. However, I would be happy to contribute in this capacity and monitor flags, migrate posts more quickly when needed, etc. More than any of that, having a diamond next to every post will make me more focused on being patient, constructive, and fair.

Answer (score 14):

> ## **[Ashwani Soni](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/3512/ashwani)**

Good luck to all of the candidates! Below is my response:-

> 1. **What voting practices would you encourage users to adopt?** This kind of dates back to [Why aren't people voting?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/102) and how to encourage a positive community through voting. How can we use our votes to encourage useful questions and answers?

For the new contributors to community I will introduce in brief about the voting system including the page [how to ask]. If a contributor posts a good, well researched and formatted question I will vote up that question which automatically works as encouragement. Also, will let them know by comment.

---

> 2. **Are you currently employed by Salesforce (Such as the Developer Evangelists)?** We've previously had [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) as a moderator who was at the time on the Salesforce Developer Evangelists team. I felt this was a large benefit to the SFSE community as a bridge into Salesforce. It's certainly not a requirement to being a moderator.

I do not work for Salesforce.com but, I believe it should not matter much as we have a lot contributors from Salesforce. We have many other ways to escalate things.

---

> 3. **How do you plan to manage the quality of new user posts?** We get a flood of new users each month, and in general that is a good thing! We want our community to grow. But the question quality is often quite poor, and there is a learning curve to adding valuable content on the Stack Exchange, with different subtleties for questions and answers.

If there is a new user, I will encourage them to go through [how to ask] section and in addition I will provide the specific thing they are missing in their post which would make sense.
If there is some typo or error which is very obvious then I can make that change itself in addition, I will post a comment how they can format their post for better visibility.

---

> 4. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

The best way is to communicate the behavior with user and also understand their point. If it still seems negligence than I should warn the user about the behavior. 
After that I would like to discuss the behavior with other moderators before taking any critical decision.

---

> 5. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

It is a rare case but yes if this happens, address the moderator by some message or chat. I would like to add the comment on the closed question if mods can do this so they can respond in context otherwise, post the concern on meta exchange. 
There have been few posts happen on Stackoverflow for these type of issues and resolved on meta-stackexchange.

---

> 6. **As a moderator, how can we help to increase the acceptance rate?** being with the site for few years now, one thing I see different compared to salesforce developer forums or success community is a large percentage of our questions stays open without any accepted answers. how can moderators pitch in to help increase this and what considerations should be taken care in doing this?

As soon as the question get the answer I would post the comment under the question to let the user know that they can accept it as answer if this resolves the query. Also, I would like to post comment periodically (few times) to check if they can accept it or try to know why they should not accept it as answer.

---

> 7. **How would you encourage User participation off SFSE?** I haven't been fortunate to go to Dreamforce (yet!), but do attend the Salesforce World Tour in London and I've often seen posts around Dreamforce and other World Tour meetups which is great. How might a moderator go about encouraging people to engage outside of Stack Exchange?

I do have access to various official Salesforce user and developer local groups. I can introduce them with the Stackexchange and explain the advantages of being a contributor here.

In addition, lot of developers have been joined to this community by seeing me. Some of them are on top.

---

> 8. **How would you be managing the flag/action to be taken on the SFSE in parallel to your daily work?** As the site in continuously growing and everyday new users joining it. This would generate a lot of expected and unexpected posts to the site which require action by moderators. I would like the know response time to be taken by moderator to resolve those actions. Do you commit to allocate a time slot to investigate and resolve flags?

Answering my own question, I always have time to spend on community during the day. I have been doing this for years for other channels as well so, I have learned how we can manage conflicts. And when I say time it means the quality time.

I am thinking to distribute my time as, I would spend 1 hour in the Morning, 1 hour in the Evening, half hour in night. Thats the minimum feasible time to me. Maximum I can spend 3-4 hours continuosly.

---

> 9. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

A moderator must encourage its site contributors. Must response to any activity with patience and putting himself in shoes of the person whom you are responding. I am strictly against the showing mod privileges unnecessarily. I have goal to make this community no. 1 that I can only do if I am moderator.

---

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Being a moderator, I will have more capability to handle flags and also I will be much serious about any action I do on site. This is an encouragement for me.

Answer (score 14):

## **[Mohith Shrivastava](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/645/mohith-shrivastava)**

> **1.What voting practices would you encourage users to adopt? This kind of dates back to Why aren't people voting?** and how to encourage a positive community through voting. How can we use our votes to encourage useful questions and answers?

I will look for new comers and if there is even a small and Sciencere effort which provides a minute clue and close to answer I will upvote and even request individuals to upvote .This would encourage new comer to get better and better with time .Also use the chat feature to open rooms and chat in person with new contributors to give them full support for them to contribute ,learn and grow with the community.

> **2.Are you currently employed by Salesforce (Such as the Developer Evangelists)?** We've previously had @metadaddy as a moderator who was at the time on the Salesforce Developer Evangelists team. I felt this was a large benefit to the SFSE community as a bridge into Salesforce. It's certainly not a requirement to being a moderator.

I am salesforce MVP so there are certain privileges and access i can leverage in favor of community .As MVP we have access to product managers and also ability to raise a case or use success community private groups to seek help ,Would leverage that for this community.

> **3.How do you plan to manage the quality of new user posts?** We get a flood of new users each month, and in general that is a good thing! We want our community to grow. But the question quality is often quite poor, and there is a learning curve to adding valuable content on the Stack Exchange, with different subtleties for questions and answers.

Immediately negative voting can demoralize the new comer .A nice little message like "Welcome to Community" and guiding them on how to ask question.I do not mind spending extra minute to edit their question and format them to explain basics of how to form a question and present to increase chances of getting an answer

> 4.How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I will Schedule an skype or zoom meeting and talk gently over the issue .The conversation should give a soft and warm feeling but if the issue keeps growing then a final warning can be sent and some strict guidelines will be given .

> 5.How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Start a discussion around the situation in mail and listen his/her perspective and then explain my perspective and mutually we can agree upon whats appropriate based on situation .

> **6.As a moderator, how can we help to increase the acceptance rate?** being with the site for few years now, one thing I see different compared to salesforce developer forums or success community is a large percentage of our questions stays open without any accepted answers. how can moderators pitch in to help increase this and what considerations should be taken care in doing this?

Many times I have seen that the question asker agrees that the question is answered but still forgets to mark it answered .I will leave a comment there to request him to mark as answered .Similarly if something is very obvious that the answer is correct ,will leave a comment for asker to provide reasons on why he thinks none of the answers solves the question

> **7.How would you encourage User participation off SFSE?** I haven't been fortunate to go to Dreamforce (yet!), but do attend the Salesforce World Tour in London and I've often seen posts around Dreamforce and other World Tour meetups which is great. How might a moderator go about encouraging people to engage outside of Stack Exchange?

A discussion post can be put together on the meta site where the info about events and how one can contribute to those events(User Group meet ups/Dev talks) can be explained

> **8.How would you be managing the flag/action to be taken on the SFSE in parallel to your daily work?** As the site in continuously growing and everyday new users joining it. This would generate a lot of expected and unexpected posts to the site which require action by moderators. I would like the know response time to be taken by moderator to resolve those actions. Do you commit to allocate a time slot to investigate and resolve flags?

I spent 4 hours everyday on this site ,so not an issue to commit for time slot and I love what I do here more than anything .

> 9.In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Moderators are leaders and act as a bridge between the community and the external world .They monitor the community ,look into flagged posts ,resolve unexpected disputes and promote the community and take it to next level.Speak about the community on stages and events like dreamforce,local dev groups and other events

> 10.In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Being moderator will make me a better leader .This will encourage me to work as a team for the community and not just build my personal reputation over here .A real leader takes everybody along and this community is amazing and being moderator I want to encourage young developers to learn and contribute to the community .A community can teach you how to collaborate and learn and there are many qualities you learn in group that you can never learn if you are individual .

Comment: great answer to Q10 mohit, your blogs and answers i have helped me many times in getting around things. Spending 4 hrs everyday is a big effort, happy to see that you accepted it with a smile, i am sure you have done more than that on many days. All the best !

Comment: Thanks @AnilShivaraj:)